# How to deploy smart contract to main ethereum network

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I am tring to deploy our ERC20 token in main net it gives an error Error: exceeds block gas limit. 
First I download or sync whole blockchain using geth command ( `geth --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024 --rpcport 8546 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"` )

Then I create a new account using `web3.personal.newAccount('password')`

Then I am send 0.01 ether this account but when Y trying get balance using `web3.eth.getBalance('address')` it shows `0` ether I trying this also `web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0x537eda319150390c2daf11d09d5840cf3bf06344'), 'ether').toNumber(10)`

Then I trying to deploy using `truffle migrate --reset --network` live it gives an `Error: exceeds block gas limit.`

Comment: Why are you using the main-net? first try it on test net and if it works there then try it on main. I will suggest you to use www.remix.ethereum.org over truffle.

Comment: i successfully test on rinkeby network its works fine. but i'm trying to deploy in main network it gives an error https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0xa07f28b6b0c512a508375666cdc345c51642c7e9

Answer (score 1):

take a closer look at the gas default in the truffle migration script for your contract and increase the gas limit  ie (number)_contract.js

// Set a maximum amount of gas and `from` address for the deployment
deployer.deploy(A, {gas: 4612388, from: "0x...."});   call to the deployer.deply API

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try deploying to main net with remix.ethereum.org first. I've had similar problems minting a contract with hardhat, then tried on remix and it worked without any warnings.

As per the error itself, i found that i needed to supply more gas in order to mint to main net from hardhat, but remix does it automatically and it is much easier to deploy.